# Arabic characters (effective power bug) crash my swift iOS app. how do I properly sanitize inputs to avoid this and related problems?

Tags: ios, swift, input, fonts, arabic

the text that caused the crash is the following: 
[image]

the error occurred at the following line:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: DBL_MAX)
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)
let attributes = [
  NSFontAttributeName:font , 
  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle
]
var rect = text.boundingRectWithSize(size, options:.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
```

where text variable contains the inputted string
parastyle is declared as follows:

```
let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paraStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

My initial idea is that the system font can't handle these characters and I need to do an **NSCharacterSet**, but I'm not sure how to either just ban characters that'll crash my app or make it so i can handle this input (ideal). I don't want to ban emojis/emoticons either.

Thanks!

Comment: Apple has stated that the are addressing tis problem. It is not as simple as sanitizing against any character, it is a complex rendering issue.

Comment: ok, but as it stands there is nothing I can do? Can I, say, ban any input with the character "冗" or " ॣ"?

Comment: also, sorry to not put the image, i assumed stack overflow people were savvy enough to find it themselves...(it's easy to find on other sites)
edit: apparently you need 10 reputation points to post images also, so can't do

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but some information and that possibly provids a way code way to avoid it.

Updated to information from [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/05/27/text_message_unicode_ios_osx_vulnerability/):

The problem isn’t with the Arabic characters themselves, but in how the unicode representing them is processed by CoreText, which is a library of software routines to help apps display text on screens.

The bug causes CoreText to access memory that is invalid, which forces the operating system to kill off the currently running program: which could be your text message app, your terminal, or in the case of the notification screen, a core part of the OS.

From Reddit but this may not be completely correct:

It only works when the message has to be abbreviated with ‘…’. This is usually on the lock screen and main menu of Messages.app.

The words effective and power can be anything as long as they’re on two different lines, which forces the Arabic text farther down the message where some of the letters will be replaced with ‘…’

The crash happens when the first dot replaces part of one of the Arabic characters (they require more than one byte to store) Normally there are safety checks to make sure half characters aren’t stored, but this replacement bypasses those checks for whatever reason.

Comment: but in my app, there is no abbreviating. it must happen because of the word break.

Comment: It could be that the word-break splits the an Arabic character in the middle. That can also happen with many characters that require two UTF-16 code units to represent them such as most emoji.

Comment: it's 2021 and it doesn't look that they fixed it

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the next category:

```
static NSString *const CRASH_STRING = @"\u0963h \u0963 \u0963";

@implementation NSString (CONEffectivePower)

- (BOOL)isDangerousStringForCurrentOS
{
    if (IS_IOS_7_OR_LESS || IS_IOS_8_4_OR_HIGHER) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self containsEffectivePowerText];
}

- (BOOL)containsEffectivePowerText
{
     return [self containsString:CRASH_STRING];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter all characters to have same directionality. Unfortunately, I'm only aware of such API in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getDirectionality%28char%29).

Comment: But that is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try. This is a bug in the operating system that will be fixed. It's not your problem. If you try to fix it, you are just wasting your time. And you are very likely to introduce bugs - when you say you "sanitise" input that means you cannot handle some perfectly fine input.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work at develops a multiplatform group video chat. 
In Crashlytics report we started noticing that some users are "effectively" trolling iOS users using this famous unicode sequence.
We can't just sit and wait for Apple to fix this bug.

So, I've worked on this problem, this is the shortest crashing sequence I got:

```
// unichar representation
unichar crashChars[8] = {1585, 1611, 32, 2403, 32, 2403, 32, 2403}; 

// string representation
NSString *crashString = @"\u0631\u064b \u0963 \u0963 \u0963"
```

So, I decided to filter out all text messages that contains two `U+0963` 'ॣ' symbols with one symbol between them (hope you are able to decipher this phrase)

My code from `NSString+Extensions` category.

```
static const unichar kDangerousSymbol = 2403;

- (BOOL)isDangerousUnicode {
    NSUInteger distance = 0;
    NSUInteger charactersFound = 0;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
        unichar character = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (charactersFound) {
            distance++;
        }

        if (distance > 2) {
            charactersFound = 0;
        }

        if (kDangerousSymbol == character) {
            charactersFound++;
        }

        if (charactersFound > 1 && distance > 0) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Lousy Specta test:

```
SpecBegin(NSStringExtensions)

describe(@"NSString+Extensions", ^{

    //....

    it(@"should detect dangerous Unicode sequences", ^{
        expect([@"\u0963 \u0963" isDangerousUnicode]).to.beTruthy();
        expect([@"\u0631\u064b \u0963 \u0963 \u0963" isDangerousUnicode]).to.beTruthy();

        expect([@"\u0631\u064b \u0963  \u0963  \u0963" isDangerousUnicode]).to.beFalsy();
    });

    //....
});

SpecEnd
```

I'm not sure if it's OK to "discriminate" messages with too many "devanagari vowel sign vocalic ll".

I'm open to corrections, suggestions, criticism :).

I would love to see a better solution to this problem.

Comment: "effective. 
      Power
           لُلُصّبُلُلصّبُررً ॣ&#160;ॣh ॣ ॣ
 冗"